# How much for a person traveling from Ghana to US needs in to purchase tickets to US

Tags: tickets

How much does a person need to travel from Ghama to US to prove they have sufficient funds to live on here in the US

Comment: The close votes are baffling.  If anything, this is probably a duplicate, but I didn't find an obvious candidate in a quick search.  But it's certainly about travel, and it is not at all "too broad."

Comment: You're not really asking about purchasing tickets are you? They have a fixed price from a company, just pay it and you get a ticket. If this is about getting through customs/immigration it should be edited to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like, I'm afraid, yet another variation on an unfortunately common scam.  To answer your question: There is no definite amount; it depends on the duration of the person's visit and the specific activities anticipated during the visit.

Scammers commonly claim that they need a certain amount of money before they can get a visa, or to purchase a plane ticket, or some other prerequisite to their travel.  They also frequently claim to be traveling from one of a small number of countries, prominently including Ghana and Russia.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to phoog's answer about how much money: in addition to having funds to pay for the trip (and spending most or all of one's savings for a brief vacation will alone be disqualifying), the applicant (assuming that a diplomatic, dual-intent, or immigrant visa isn't sought) must rebut the US-legally-imposed presumption that *visa seekers have immigrant intent*. This requires showing reasons why the applicant would return home after the trip: spouse, children, other family, property, other savings or assets, job, etc.

Without proof to rebut the presumption, the visa application will be denied.

Comment: There are some visa seekers who do not need to rebut the presumption of immigrant intent, of course, such as those seeking immigrant visas, dual-intent visas, or diplomatic visas.

Comment: @phoog. Yes, you're right. I've just amended my answer. Thanks.